# Password in Jenkins shell build

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to clone a repository in Jenkins. Due to reasons I have to do a manual git clone instead of using the built-in Source-Code Management. The repository I am cloning, only has https available. My question is how do I supply the following command with a password without entering it in the url.

```
 git clone https://username@repository.domain.com/scm/cus/repo.git"
```

The target repository is a Stash repository. When I try to use the username:password format, I get a HTTP 400 error. Anybody knows what I can do as an alternative? I also tried doing the same command from the CLI but there I also receive the HTTP 400 error. The only way it works is when I supply the password manually in the CLI.

Fyi: running Git 1.7.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the password had some special characters in it. I URL encoded all the characters and now it works.